# ¿Cómo obtener frecuencias de una lista de números mayores a cierto umbral?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un archivo.dat que tiene datos de precipitacion (un dato por dia) durante 56 años, dispuestos de la siguiente manera:

```
dia mes año precipitacion

1 1 1956 50
2 1 1956 2
3 1 1956 0 
4 1 1956 0
5 1 1956 100
```

Necesito armar un script en Python que me diga la cantidad de veces **por año** que se supero cierto umbral de precipitacion (por ejemplo que se supero el numero 50 correspondiente a la cuarta columna). Estoy tratando de ver como puedo armar una tabla de frecuencia de tal manera de que me queden los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
Año    Frecuencia
1958   6
1959   2
1960   5
```

y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de la comunidad y de paso ganar tu primera medalla! También que te pases por  [como elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para así mejorar la tuya y ayuda a los usuarios a responder de manera mas efectiva y precisa. Si tienes cualquier duda tienes toda la info en la sección de [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto debe solucionar tu pregunta

```
tolerancia = 50 # se contaran los mayores a este numero
resultado = { }

with open('archivo.dat') as archivo_leido:
    for line in archivo_leido:
        line_to_list = line.split();
        if len(line_to_list) == 4:
            if (not line_to_list[2] in resultado) and (int(line_to_list[3]) > tolerancia):
                resultado[line_to_list[2]] = 1
            elif int(line_to_list[3]) > tolerancia:
                resultado[line_to_list[2]] += 1
            else:
                pass

# Imprimir resultados
for n in resultado:
    print(n, resultado[n])
```

Prueba archivo.dat

```
1 1 1956 50

2 1 1956 2
3 1 1956 0 
4 1 1956 0

5 1 1956 100
6 1 1956 85
7 1 1956 35
8 1 1957 45
9 1 1958 56
10 1 1959 120
11 1 1959 100
12 1 1959 30
13 1 1959 66
```

Resultado:

```
1956 2
1958 1
1959 3
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias por tu ayuda!! Me corrió perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de como administres los datos, la solución puede llegar a ser muy distinta.

#### 1. Python basico

Si tuvieras una lista de listas o tuplas con esta información, una forma bastante simple sería usar una comprensión de listas para filtrar los valores que superen el umbral y la clase `Counter` para contar las ocurrencias:

```
lista = [ 
  (1, 1, 1956, 50),
  (2, 1, 1956, 2),
  (3, 1, 1956, 0),
  (4, 1, 1956, 0),
  (5, 1, 1956, 100) 
]

from collections import Counter
umbral = 30
c = dict(Counter([elemento[2] for elemento in lista if elemento[3] > umbral]))
print(c)

> {1956: 2}
```

Esto te retornará un diccionario con los años y la cantidad de veces que se ha superado el umbral

#### 2. Pandas

Si usas `pandas` para administrar tus datos (lo cual es sumamente recomendable) la solución podría ser:

```
import pandas as pd

lista = [ 
  (1, 1, 1956, 50),
  (2, 1, 1956, 2),
  (3, 1, 1956, 0),
  (4, 1, 1956, 0),
  (5, 1, 1956, 100) 
]

umbral = 30

df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns=['dia', 'mes', 'anio', 'precipitacion'])

# Filtramos las filas que superan el umbral
superiores = df.loc[df['precipitacion'] > umbral]

# agrupamos por año y contamos la cantidad de los mismos
print(superiores.groupby(['anio']).size())


anio
1956    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda!!